# Windows 7 replaced my image with its cached thumbnail of that image... can I recover it?

Tags: windows, updates, thumbnails, tiff

So frustrating. I have a huge 700MB tiff file. I edited it for an hour. I saved my edits and closed it.

Windows showed the older version of the image in its thumbnail. I googled for a fix. Someone suggested opening it in windows photo viewer, rotating it, then closing it. The theory is that the rotated version will force a new correct thumbnail, albeit sideways. Then I only needed to rotate it back.

Instead, the rotated version of the image was still the old, wrong version. And when I closed picture viewer, it overwrote the file without even prompting me (thank you, microsoft).

Now my hour of work is lost because the edited picture has been overwritten by this rotated thumbnail of the image (and yes, I reopened in photoshop to confirm it's not just a thumbnail issue anymore... the whole file is overwritten and ruined).

Is there any way to get the edited version back, with or without a correct thumbnail?

Comment: Try some undelete programs. I have used one called R-studio  that isn't free but there must be lots of free ones.. I often here of revuca, here  try https://www.piriform.com/recuva

Answer (score 0):

If you've got the previous version feature enabled, just right-click the file -> properties -> Previous versions. There click the previous version and click open to verify it is the right one, then restore.

If you haven't enabled this feature... Well the odds of hetting that file back are kinda low (depending on how much you write to the disk). **NOW DO NOT INSTALL OR WRITE ANYTHING** to the disk the file is on. If the original file didn't get overwritten by anything (it is possible the new version got written somewhere else on the disk), it should still be there, just not visible by the system.

Try one of the file recovery utilities like DataRecovery http://tokiwa.qee.jp/EN/dr.html (just download it onto another drive).
If all fails, you are probably out of luck. You could try one of the local file recovery companies (the really expensive ones who physically disassemble the hdd in order to get to the data that was there.) if the data is  **REALLY**  important.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions so far. unfortunately, undelete programs didn't work and there's no previous version. at this point it makes more sense to redo the work than spend another hour researching and trying extra steps. Lesson learned I guess... if windows wants to be stupid about thumbnails, just let it.